# How can I move a dom element created after the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a plugin named anchorific.js to create named anchors and corresponding menu on the fly from h3 tags. 
To get it working in a .net page I had to move the div containing the menu so it was the last item on the page.
Now I want to move the div elsewhere, but running .append() after the anchorific code won't work. What can I do to move this element?

Comment: plz post your code to get help

Answer (score 0):

To make dom manipulations after the dom is loaded simply use `$(document).ready(function() {})` or `$(window).load(function() {})` in jQuery or if you prefer `window.onload = function() {}` in vanilla javascript.

Comment: That doesn't work for some reason. I assumed it was because that the element I am moving was created in js in code run after the document loads